# Changing input background on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple effect that whenever anybody enters anything into my search field, upon hitting "enter", a simple little loading gif appears inside of the input box.

You can see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/9KEKa/1/, and here is the raw HTML, CSS, and JS:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="transition-width" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="hide" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/* General */
.hide {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.transition-width {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease;  
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease;  
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease;  
    -ms-transition: width 0.5s ease;  
    transition: width 0.5s ease;  
}

/* Search Form */
form input { 
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/7BKx4xr.png') no-repeat right;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: 61px;
}

.searching { background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ayJ7sYg.gif') no-repeat right; } 

form input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }

form input::-moz-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }

form input:-moz-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }

form input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }

form input:focus { 
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    cursor: auto;
    width: 200px; 
}

form input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #666; }

form input:focus::-moz-input-placeholder { color: #666; }

form input:focus:-moz-input-placeholder { color: #666; }

form input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #666; }
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
$(function () {
    $('.search form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault

        $('.search form input.transition-width').addClass('searching');
    });
});
```

All I'm trying to do is add the class "searching" which contains the animated gif that I want as the background.

A lot of my code seems correct, but I may just be having a mental block. Hopefully it's a simple issue that can be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your capture key for enter was incorrect.  Also, the "loading effect" will only work for a use case where one hits "enter."  I have left your CSS and HTML as intact and without change.

## JS

```
    $('.transition-width').keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
         $('input.transition-width').blur(); 
        $('input.transition-width').addClass('searching');
    }    
  });
```

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/58uQU/1/

Answer (score 1):

3 Things:

1. Your selector for `.searching` isn't specific enough. It's being
   overriden by `input:focus` and thus having no effect.
2. You need to
   call the function preventDefault not just point to it.
   `e.preventDefault();`
3. Your event handler is using the wrong
   selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try `e.preventDefault();` instead of `e.preventDefault`.

And your selector should not be `.search form` .. when your sourcecode has no such class element before the form in question. It should be just `form` in that case.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KEKa/2/)